# Pass Option Select Value to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

im trying to get the value each time a client selects a option from my Dropdown list to send it back to controller where i use the value on creating a file and then refreshing the page but im unable to do so

This is my Dropdownlist:

```html
 <select id="sel0">
 <option value="">Todos</option>
   @foreach (var item in Model.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
             {
 <option value="@lines">@lines</option>
             }
 </select>
```

This is my Ajax Call:

```js
 $('#sel0').on('change', function () {
                       dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();
                   });

                   $("form").submit(function () { 
                       $.ajax({
                           url: '@Url.Action("MethodName","HomePosController")',
                           type: 'POST',
                           cache: false,
                           data: { Selected: $("#sel0").val() },
                           success: function (data) {
                               //
                           }
                       });
                   });
```

and this is my Controller its named 'HomePosController':

```
 public ActionResult MethodName(string Selected)
    {
        var db = new ArponClientPosContext();

        String value = Selected;
        var json4 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Selected);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\potzolcalli.brain.arpon.com\valorselected.txt", json4);
        return View("~/Views/HomePos/Index.cshtml", db.Pos.ToList());
    }
```

But whenever y select a option of my dropdown nothing happens, the page its not refreshed nor the file is created what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you submitting the form, or just changing the value in the dropdown?  The description implies the latter, but the code is looking for the former.

Comment: im just changing the value of the dropdown how can i trigger the ajax ? i want it to trigger after a value is changed in the dropdown list

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be on dropdown change then you have to send ajax call in change event :

```
$('#sel0').on('change', function () {

   dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();

   $.ajax({
                       url: '@Url.Action("MethodName","HomePos")',
                       type: 'POST',
                       cache: false,
                       data: { Selected: $("#sel0").val() },
                       success: function (data) {
                           //
                       }
                   });
```

and you have to not write complete Controller class name,  you have to skip the **Controller** postfix, it is convention which is followed by Url helpers in mvc, that way your url generated will be wrong and ajax call will fail.

Answer (score 1):

> whenever y select a option of my dropdown nothing happens

Well, this happens:

```
dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();
```

But that doesn't invoke the AJAX request.  It doesn't do much of anything, really.

> how can i trigger the ajax ? i want it to trigger after a value is changed in the dropdown list

In that case you want to do that on the `select` element's `change` event.  Currently you perform the AJAX request here:

```
$("form").submit(function () { 
    // AJAX
});
```

That is, you perform the request in the form's submit event.  Just add it to the drop down's change event instead:

```
$('#sel0').on('change', function () {
    dataTable.columns('.fechas').search(this.value).draw();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MethodName","HomePosController")',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { Selected: $("#sel0").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            //
        }
    });
});
```

> the page its not refreshed

Well, no.  That won't happen in an AJAX request.  Currently your `success` callback is empty, so nothing will happen on the page.  Whatever you want to happen would need to be put in that callback.

Comment: well now i understand abit more but then how can i cod ein my Succes: function that triggers another actionresult from my controller to load page again? is this posible? @David

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: If you want to refresh the page or navigate to a new page in any way then why use AJAX in the first place?  Just use a normal form.

Comment: im dont know how to use normal form do you have a example?

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: Well, any MVC tutorial will have that.  It starts with a "@using Html. BeginForm"